# Windows Update Error 0x80070005 on Server 2016

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, windows-update

I frequently get error 0x80070005 on Windows 2016 servers when running Windows Update.  It's really odd, other updates will install fine, and often future updates will install as well.  Updates also install fine on other servers in the same domain.  They all point to the same WSUS server and are all on the same OS (Windows Server 2016) and are configured identically on the same domain.

I've tried many of the things I've found in google search.  SFC, changing permissions on the app pool folder, deleting the software distribution folder, etc.

Any idea what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Are we supposed to instinctively know what error 0x80070005 is or did you want us to Google it and then come back and answer your question? Why don't you tell us what error 0x80070005 is?

Comment: 0x80070005 means that systemfiles are defect, you have to run `chkdsk /perf /scan` and afterwards `sfc /scannow` reboot and afterwards retry, if it's the same, you need to redo the same but delete windows update cache, had this issue some days ago on some laptops and @joeqwerty advanced it technicians knows the top 10 codes xd

Comment: 0x80070005 - is "access denied" error.
You could do a complete WU reset and try to update the server via Internet (avoiding WSUS). If nothing helps and you are stuck, then you might want to debug this deeper. You could try running Sysinternal's Process Monitor and filter on ACCESS DENIED results. Be careful doing this on busy production server though.